# inconvertable types weird error

Tags: java

I keep getting an error dealing with inconvertable types but, I have edited this file before in a similar way and this did not happen before.

here is the bit with the error

```
if (Stream == null) { // bad operand types for binary operator '=='
Stream = (g.a) getField("stream").get(c); //inconvertable types
System.out.println("THIS");
}
if (player == null) {                   // bad operand types for binary operator '=='
player = (b.a.) getField("hg").get(c); //inconvertable types
```

What I am doing is replacing the (b.a) which was (player) with the new file which is obfuscated. So the new Player is inside of the folder b and named a

Comment: Is `Stream` a variable? What is its type? What does `getField("stream").get(c)` return? What is `g.a`?

Comment: here maybe this will help, Stream is indeed a variable
http://pastebin.com/aKVq22M2

Comment: What's really weird are the naming conventions you're using and the kludge of static methods and variables crammed into a single class. What on earth are `b.a` and `g.a`? Static inner classes defined somewhere in the package?

Comment: This class loads instances of multiple other classes to "copy" a java client. The naming conventions are weird because the client is obfuscated using Jshrink or Proguard